# How to install an homebrew package behind a proxy?

Tags: homebrew, proxy

I'm working behind a proxy. When I installed homebrew I've modified the official command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

by adding a `-x` option to tell curl about the proxy:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -x proxy.mydomain.com:3128 -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and it works well. But now I want to install openssl:

```
brew install openssl
```

and logically, the proxy is not detected:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to homebrew.bintray.com port 443: Connection refused
Error: Failed to download resource "openssl"
```

If I set the environment variables as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Tips-N'-Tricks.md#using-homebrew-behind-a-proxy):

```
http_proxy=proxy.mydomain.com:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.mydomain.com:3128
ALL_PROXY=proxy.mydomain.com:3128
```

I obtain the same error. Adding `http:` or `https:` before doesn't change the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To run Homebrew or Curl behind a proxy :

```
export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy:port
```

or

```
export ALL_PROXY=proxyIP:port
```

After this is done, installation worked smoothly.

Comment: `$http_proxy` is not defined usually.

Comment: Setting `$ALL_PROXY` worked for me.

Comment: Depending on the brew command you use, you also have to set the proxy for git with `git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`

Comment: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 501

Comment: Works on zsh shell, doesn't work on fish shell.. so surprising

Comment: On fish, it might help to enclose the proxy:port into " "

Answer (score 11):

Try run `brew` like this:

```
http_proxy=https://user:password@proxy:port https_proxy=https://user:password@proxy:port brew install PACKAGE
```

The source is here: https://juanchorossi.com/osx-set-brew-proxy-server/

Answer (score 6):

For [SOCKS5 proxy](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/11114#issuecomment-62933075):

```
ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:9001 brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all_proxy=<proxy_domain>:<port> brew install <package>
```

I didn't explicitly include the `http://` or `https://` prefix in the proxy domain. Worked for me with macOS Sierra and Homebrew 1.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, type this:

```
http_proxy=http://IP:PORT https_proxy=http://IP:PORT brew install PACKAGE
```

for me, was behind IIIT proxy and trying to install python3, so this worked:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080 https_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080 brew install python3
```