# Homebrew not detecting latest Xcode and Command Line Tools, and not uninstalling them either

Tags: mojave, xcode, homebrew

I have macOS Mojave version 10.14.5 installed with Xcode version 10.2.1 and Command Line Tools installed using `xcode-select --install`. All problem started when I tried to install `youtube-dl` formula on my system by running:

`brew install youtube-dl`

The output I get is:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: Your Xcode (1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```

Again, if I run `xcode-select --install`, I get:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Running:

`xcode-select -v`

returns

```
xcode-select version 2354
```

(I do not know what this means) and running:

`xcode-select -p`

yields

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Owing to these issues, I tried to uninstall Homebrew (with a plan to reinstall it afresh) by running the command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

but it gives the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Next, I tried to uninstall Homebrew using the `unbrew.rb` script available at [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/SteveBenner/11254428) but it seems not to remove Homebrew. I tried running it with and without sudo. Even after doing this, running `brew config` returns:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.3.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 751334a257d81851e68da7ab390982d4e9fdf909
Last commit: 1 year, 10 months ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 3fd7a855a1a357654a4a9a455162761841a4809d
Core tap last commit: 1 year, 10 months ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: N/A
Git: 2.20.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Perl: /opt/local/bin/perl => /opt/local/bin/perl5.24
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Java: N/A
macOS: 10.14.5-x86_64
Xcode: 1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
CLT: N/A
X11: N/A
MacPorts/Fink: /opt/local/bin/port
```

Running `brew doctor` outputs the following:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.

Error: Unrecognized Mach-O load command: 0x32
```

Is my Homebrew broken by my attempts at uninstalling it? What can I do to repair Homebrew and all these errors in pointing to the right Xcode and command line tools?

I had tried updating Homebrew by running `brew update` earlier without success. Running:

```
brew update
```

returns:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew failed!
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask failed!
```

Comment: Do you still have Xcode installed? Where is the location Xcode.app bundle? Is Xcode installed from the App Store? Go to Mac App Store, search for Xcode and see if the button besides the app icon reads "Open" or "Get"?

Comment: Yes, I always have Xcode installed and updated. To verify, I had gone to the Apple Developer site, opted to install the latest release of Xcode and it redirected to the App Store where the button next to the app indeed read "open'. The Xcode.app is in /Applications.

Comment: The installed version of Homebrew appears to be too outdated. Your installed version appears to be 1.3.2 while the current public version is 2.1.6. Try running `brew update` to see if it upgrades Homebrew.

Comment: I had tried that a number of times without success before attempting to uninstall Homebrew. Tried again now, have posted the outcome as an edit to the question.

Comment: The error appears self explanatory. Something is preventing you from connecting to GitHub's servers which hosts Homebrew software's backend. Check if you can access the `githubusercontent.com` and `github.com` via a Web browser. Is a proxy or firewall preventing you from connecting?

Comment: I can access them from Safari/Firefox. There is a proxy active here, but it is set systemwide in network.

Comment: In fact I have earlier used Homebrew over this same network.

Comment: How about checking if the port mentioned in the error message (port 443)? Is it allowed network communication?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95575/discussion-between-damaihati-and-nimesh-neema).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is evident from the output of `brew config`, your installation of Homebrew is pretty outdated. Also, as mentioned in your [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363569/homebrew-not-detecting-latest-xcode-and-command-line-tools-and-not-uninstalling#comment483220_363569), you have a proxy active in your system. This explains why Homebrew installation is failing to connect unable to the Homebrew software's server counterpart via port 443, which  hosted on GitHub.

Follow the instructions in the following answer to update your installation of Homebrew to current version:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232770/279727

If you run into an error similar to:

> Error: Permission denied

Run:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
```

to resolve it.

If you get the following error:

> Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed 
>   formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin. 
>   Consider setting the PATH for example like so: 
>   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Run the command-line mentioned in the last line.

Once you have Homebrew updated, run `brew cleanup` to remove any broken symlinks.

The current public version of Homebrew is 2.1.6. You can check if your installation of Homebrew is up-to-date by running `brew config` and matching the value with the `HOMEBREW_VERSION:` key in the output.