# "A newer Command Line Tools release is available" but no updates in System Preferences or AppStore

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, homebrew

When I upgrade a package, homebrew prompts this:

```
==> Upgrading mysql@5.7
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
```

I have XCode Version 11.3 (11C29) installed, and no updates in System Preferences or App Store

[image]

[image]

Opening Xcode does not prompt me to install command line tools either, how can I get the latest version?

Comment: Though the above link is for general update of CLT, but if homebrew is at fault, see. 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363569/homebrew-not-detecting-latest-xcode-and-command-line-tools-and-not-uninstalling?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370695/cant-install-homebrew-on-macos-mojave-installer-doesnt-recognize-command-line?rq=1

Comment: I had the same issue. If no updates show up in Software Update, you may have to reinstall Command Line Tools. You can either download it from the link mentioned in the Homebrew warning, or you can delete it and just use `xcode-select --install` as described in https://swissmacuser.ch/brew-doctor-a-newer-command-line-tools-release-is-available-but-software-update-cannot-find-it/

Comment: None of these solutions work for me. I've followed the instructions to delete (with `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and then reinstall (with `sudo xcode-select --install`) but keep getting the same warning.